# Плавное изменение position для кнопки

Tags: javascript, css3, css-animation

https://codepen.io/Raneto4ka/full/bGEdzZj смотреть так, чтобы была вертикальная полоса прокрутки.

Суть в чем: есть блок с длинным текстом. Пока пользователь не долистал до конца страницы кнопка болтается поверх текста. Как только достиг конца документа, эта кнопка встает под текстом, меняя своё положение с фиксированного на статичное.
Всё бы хорошо, но только процесс перехода происходит резко, скачком. Можно ли реализовать эту идею плавно и красиво? код здесь: https://codepen.io/Raneto4ka/pen/bGEdzZj

```js
var timeout = false;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (timeout !== false) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  const button = document.querySelector('.button');
  let clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;
  let documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight ? document.documentElement.scrollHeight : document.body.scrollHeight;
  let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
  
  if((documentHeight - clientHeight) <= scrollTop) {
    button.classList.add('endScroll');
  }
  else {
    button.classList.remove('endScroll');
  }
  }, 250);
};
```

```css
.menu {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff500;
  padding: 16px;
}
.list {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ddd500;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.button.endScroll {
  position: static;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium aperiam doloribus vero possimus, harum quo ratione nisi iusto eaque magnam perferendis? Quisquam animi consectetur adipisci fugiat qui obcaecati asperiores suscipit?
  Illo quaerat praesentium quia quasi fugit optio doloribus consequatur. Asperiores ad nisi illo neque aliquid sit, quasi repellendus architecto nam error, ea tenetur veniam, expedita aperiam itaque! Est, tempora labore.
  Fugiat error, neque necessitatibus blanditiis sint cum voluptates recusandae quae, nulla minus quibusdam ipsa dolore, impedit adipisci quam vel ipsam voluptatem aliquid! Dolores nostrum excepturi dolor modi nihil, cupiditate necessitatibus.</div>
    <div class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium aperiam doloribus vero possimus, harum quo ratione nisi iusto eaque magnam perferendis? Quisquam animi consectetur adipisci fugiat qui obcaecati asperiores suscipit?
  Illo quaerat praesentium quia quasi fugit optio doloribus consequatur. Asperiores ad nisi illo neque aliquid sit, quasi repellendus architecto nam error, ea tenetur veniam, expedita aperiam itaque! Est, tempora labore.
  Fugiat error, neque necessitatibus blanditiis sint cum voluptates recusandae quae, nulla minus quibusdam ipsa dolore, impedit adipisci quam vel ipsam voluptatem aliquid! Dolores nostrum excepturi dolor modi nihil, cupiditate necessitatibus.</div>
    <div class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium aperiam doloribus vero possimus, harum quo ratione nisi iusto eaque magnam perferendis? Quisquam animi consectetur adipisci fugiat qui obcaecati asperiores suscipit?
  Illo quaerat praesentium quia quasi fugit optio doloribus consequatur. Asperiores ad nisi illo neque aliquid sit, quasi repellendus architecto nam error, ea tenetur veniam, expedita aperiam itaque! Est, tempora labore.
  Fugiat error, neque necessitatibus blanditiis sint cum voluptates recusandae quae, nulla minus quibusdam ipsa dolore, impedit adipisci quam vel ipsam voluptatem aliquid! Dolores nostrum excepturi dolor modi nihil, cupiditate necessitatibus.</div>
    <div class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium aperiam doloribus vero possimus, harum quo ratione nisi iusto eaque magnam perferendis? Quisquam animi consectetur adipisci fugiat qui obcaecati asperiores suscipit?
  Illo quaerat praesentium quia quasi fugit optio doloribus consequatur. Asperiores ad nisi illo neque aliquid sit, quasi repellendus architecto nam error, ea tenetur veniam, expedita aperiam itaque! Est, tempora labore.
  Fugiat error, neque necessitatibus blanditiis sint cum voluptates recusandae quae, nulla minus quibusdam ipsa dolore, impedit adipisci quam vel ipsam voluptatem aliquid! Dolores nostrum excepturi dolor modi nihil, cupiditate necessitatibus.</div>
  <div class="button">Clck me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы transition добавьте к кнопке -

Comment: transition  мне анимирует перемещение по оси X (свойство transform), а это не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: вам сбоку надо появление ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLeYLxY - снизу вот так анимировал

Comment: мне надо, чтоб пока человек скроллит кнопка была поверх текста, а когда доскроллил до конца, чтоб она занимала место под текстом.

Comment: Просто отступ снизу добавить нельзя, тк этой кнопки может и не быть, и тогда будет лишнее место после текста

Comment: подрихтовала ваше решение, вроде получилось как надо) Спасибо, @MaximLensky! https://codepen.io/Raneto4ka/full/bGEdzZj